# Using JavaCompiler class to compile a directory with dependencies and text files

Tags: java, compilation

Before reading what I said below and leaving, please consider helping me if you know any other way to compile a java directory with non-java files, using code.

I just tried some code (see below) to compile a directory, and it worked fine! What I want to do is including some text files and a jar file (as a dependency), but I have no idea how to do it. I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to do it and show me some sample code.

Code:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(file1.getAbsolutePath(), file2.getAbsolutePath(), file3.getAbsolutePath()));
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
boolean success = task.call();
fileManager.close();
System.out.println(success);
```

Replacing `Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(file1.getAbsolutePath(), file2.getAbsolutePath(), file3.getAbsolutePath()));` with `Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(file1.getAbsolutePath(), file2.getAbsolutePath(), file3.getAbsolutePath(), text.getAbsolutePath(), dependency.getAbsolutePath()));` will just make it not work at all, because they aren't java files.

Or maybe there is a better way to do exactly that?